# Ball touching the side of a tube -- DOUBT

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My friend has a small doubt in understanding a physics concept.

If a steel ball is dropped in a thin tube of glycerol, it will eventually reach its maximum or terminal velocity. However, if the steel ball increases in size, there is more chance of it hitting the side of the glass cylinder. So how would this affect its speed? Would it fall slower?

Thanks!

Comment: How fast do you think the ball would fall if its diameter were exactly equal to the diameter of the tube?

Comment: Please do not delete the question you've written

Comment: Even if the ball doesn't hit the walls its speed would still depend on the size of the tube, because ball induces fluid motion over distances many times its own size.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.

A few years ago I was TAing basic physics lab and we had somewhat similar exercise. Cylinder with glycerol was about 10cm (4 in) so not very thin in diameter, and it  had two bands at known positions from top. You would measure time it took to get from upper marker to lower. Variety of balls were used, including glass, steel and plastic (this were ASG balls). Diameters ranged form 5 to 10 or so millimeters. For steel ball you would have more or like place ball on the surface, and not drop it, as its descent was rapid and it wouldn't achieve terminal velocity before upper marker. Placing it in the middle was easy, but sometimes ball would slip and land near the side. And then it did fall slower. This was the case for every kind of ball to be clear.

Viscosity is transport of momentum. For laminar flow you can think of it as liquid cylinders with varying diameter slipping over each other, and the closer to the ball the higher the velocity. Somewhere far from ball velocity is zero, while next to it is same as ball velocity. If you have laminar flow (and for ball falling slow enough in glycerol it is the case), velocity profile must be continuous. So if you have ball next to the wall that's not moving it will slow down descent, as it can't transfer momentum in the direction of wall as effectively as in others.